# Testing older Rails app: circular argument reference warning, cannot load test/unit/assertions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

CentOS-6.6
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
Bundler version 1.7.11

I am attempting to patch a older RoR application that was upgraded to 4.0.1 last year.  When I run bundle exec cucumber before making any changes I now get this sort of error:

```
bundle exec cucumber

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now

cannot load such file -- test/unit/assertions (LoadError)

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/features/support/local_env.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load_code_file'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in `load_step_definitions'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'

/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_forex_rss/libexec/bundler/lib/ruby/2.2.0/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

`warning: circular argument reference - xxxx` was limited to Cucumber, which formerly was at 1.3.10.  So I updated cucumber to 1.3.19.  Now I am getting the error in active support.  Has anyone else seen this.

I had a problem with Minitest preventing this project from advancing to RoR-4.1 back last spring.  I do not know if this is pertinent or not but I include it for completeness.

In any case, who puts testing dependencies into distributed runtime code?  Why is activesupport complaining about 'test/unit/assertions'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading from Rails 4.0.1 to 4.0.13

If that doesn't work, try using Ruby 2.1.5 to see if you get the same error message. I bet some gem you're using is running into [this issue with Ruby 2.2](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10314). [Example 1](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18160/files), [Example 2](https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1902). [Example 3 from Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2ce5e08e620c3cfcf1ede3ae26e6faf4e954d2be).

The long term solution is to use Ruby 2.2 compatible gems, but by switching to 2.1.5 temporarily, you may be able to solve the problem in the short term and narrow down the specific gem versions that are causing the error.

Comment: The `def foo(bar = bar)` "convention" seems to be common in old Gems - has Ruby 2.2 changed/broken the intended behaviour, or is it just a warning that the behaviour is not well-defined?

Answer (score 0):

i just add gem 'test-unit' in Gemfile and run 'bundle install' again. It is solved to me.