# warning: circular argument reference - now when trying to open rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

Whenever I type in `rails console` in the root of the application I get this:

```
/Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
/Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/testcase (LoadError)
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/console/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:304:in `initialize_console'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:152:in `load_console'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any way to stop this from happening, so I can use the rails console. I'm on rails version 3.2.13.

Comment: Could you specify what it is you're entering in the console?

Comment: You type in `rails console` in the root of what?

Comment: I'm in the root of the application im building for this rails tutorial. Sorry, I'm just learning this language; I should've specified.

Comment: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6873211 is what I found doing a search for that error. Look through that discussion, it may help.  Let us know!  The other references I found seem to point to Compass.  What is the tutorial you are going through?  You say 'this tutorial" but I did not see where you were pointing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27717309/485864 may be that this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Im going through Kevin Skoglund's Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training. I'm learning about ActiveRecord and working in the Rails console, but I can't seem to access the console. Thanks for the help. I'll let you know if I figure something out.

Comment: @JustinLee BTW, Lynda.com has released Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training, why go for version 3?

Comment: The "circular argument reference" warning is probably unrelated to the errors - it seems to be caused by using Ruby 2.2 with old Gems that have functions like `def foo(bar = bar)` (it seems to have been a common "convention") - see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/28770015/446106

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It has been caused by **wrong access rights to the gem files**. The gems have been owned by the wrong user.

This resolved the issue for me:

1. Setting the correct user recursively: `chown -R user folder`.
2. Reinstalling the necessary gems (optional. I did this just to make sure, I didn't break something)

Unfortunately, I'm not using. Thus, I can't give you detailed instructions how to do this for rvm.